# Monochrome LCD sources

Tags: lcd

I'm planning on doing a one-off project that will need a monochrome LCD 3-4 inches wide. Unfortunately, I haven't had much luck finding what I need. Smaller screens like those salvaged from cell phones, such as the Noka 5110, and commonly used with microcontrollers are really ideal except that they are too small. I haven't had any luck searching sites like Mouser. It seems that color LCDs have mostly replaced them.

So my question is, are there any devices that would be good sources for salvaging monochrome LCDs? Cell phones, PDAs, and printers all come to mind, although I don't know if any of those fit all of my criteria. Working documentation is the most important. Many devices have nice LCDs but it isn't always possible to tell if it would be possible to get them working. Do any of you have experience working with a salvaged LCD with these qualities?

-screen width around 3-4 inches
-width:height ratio between 1:1 and 2:1
-resolution above 128x64
-matrix display, not character
-supply voltage between 3v and 5v
-can be driven by a microcontroller
-hand solderable pins or ribbons (around 0.6mm or bigger)
-datasheet or other documentation

EDIT: Rephrased question

Comment: While monochrome graphic LCD _modules_  supporting I2C (sometimes TWI is mentioned) pop up on Ebay every now and then, availability and demand dictate that color LCD  modules are going to be cheaper and more common. If you seek the classic mono LCD aesthetic, easy enough to add code for the desired tint on a color display module.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh, that's a good point. I think a parallel interface could work if the pins or pads aren't very small.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to keep looking on all the major vendors sites - Digikey, Mouser, Farnell, RS, etc. If you can't find anything suitable between them, then it's unlikely there is anything off the shelf (you can talk to display manufacturers for a custom option if the quantities are worth it)

I typed in "LCD" to Mousers search box, and I got a load of options that may fit your requirements. Here is one [example 128 X 64 monochrome display](http://uk.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Newhaven-Display/NHD-C12864GG-RN-GBW/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvkC18yXH9iIrT2x4EBez8Z9MuqLXjfujE=) for < £10, although I don't know if it has an SPI/I2C option (plenty more  [here](http://uk.mouser.com/Optoelectronics/Displays/LCD-Displays/LCD-Graphic-Display-Modules-Accessories/_/N-6j73a?Keyword=lcd&Ns=Pricing%7C0&No=25&FS=True)):

[image: Example]

Here is a [monochrome 128x64 SPI option](http://uk.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ELECTRONIC-ASSEMBLY/EA-DOGM128E-6/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvkC18yXH9iIm5JIOLURcVOHPfEFKWV/xI=) at ~£12:

[image: Example SPI]

Also, if you found a suitable colour display, why not just use this as a black/white display?

For salvage, I can think of things like photocopiers, handheld test equipment, old PDAs/personal organisers (e.g. [Palm Pilots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PalmPilot), [PSION products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psion)) that have such displays. Maybe a search on eBay might give you some other ideas.

[image: Palm Pilot] [image: PSION]

Parallel connections and [FFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_flat_cable)/FPCs

Although some of the parallel connection options can look daunting, they are not so hard to hand solder. Some are designed to be soldered directly (google "hot bar soldering" and "FFC soldering") and some are designed for a suitable socket. Here is an example of of one of my prototypes which used an FFC based display:

[image: FFC solder]

The soldering is pretty easy with plenty of flux and a drag soldering technique.

Comment: Hmm, I was surprised that this was downvoted. No, it is not a shopping question. I have looked at every single monochrome LCD on Mouser and none fit my criteria. Did you see the recent meta question about whether salvage questions should be allowed? I sort of assumed salvage would be the only option for such displays since they seem to have been mostly replaced by color LCDs. Running in black in white mode is an option but I really like the older monochrome style.

Please let me know if there is some way to edit my question to make it more appropriate.

Comment: @MrMobius - Fair enough (I didn't downvote) I answered as it's not a direct shopping question, but it will likely be seen as such by others. I didn't see the Meta question, but I personally don't mind salvage questions. I think th main issue is whether the answers will be of use to future visitors - since a display is probably quite a commonly salvaged item, then I think the answers are likely to be of future use.

Comment: Question wording wise, maybe mentioning you have already searched the major sites, and it's a salvage question for a one off project might be an idea.

Comment: PDAs and looking on eBay are both good suggestions. Finding a device with an appropriate screen isn't hard but it's not always obvious whether the LCD would have appropriate connectors, whether the voltage would be convenient to work with or whether the documentation would be sufficient. I wanted to ask here in case anyone had experience using such an LCD. So far I've collected several nice looking LCDs that are unusable for one of the above reasons and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @MrMobius - Yes, unfortunately I think the connections are where you will struggle - most graphic displays are parallel, especially the older parts. I know Newhaven do a couple of decent SPI colour displays (I have 5 here from Mouser) As Anindo says, using a grey-green and black should give you quite an authentic monochrome look. Or you could adapt your specs to accommodate a parallel display, this would certainly make it easier for you if it's possible.

Comment: @MrMobius - I just added an SPI option, see if that suits your requirements.

Comment: come to think of it, I think a parallel display might work alright if the pads are large enough. One display I have has 32 pins on a ribbon that is about a centimeter and half wide. I can't really solder wires to that kind of connector. Also, I know it's picky but it would be nice to have a resolution better than 128x64. Some are around 160x100 and that would be better.

Comment: @MrMobius - Although they look to be, some of the parallel flexible cables are not that hard to solder (see my added example) I've seen examples of people actually soldering individual wires to such cables :-)